# Image lose quality with browser's resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, zooming

I created a signature with a succession of images, so with the union of these images should come out a signature with link (for example, in the social, in the site..).

Now, while I combined these images there are a mistakes.
Only if the Browser view (this problem is only in Chrome and not in Mozilla, IE, Edge) is at 80% is displayed correctly. But in any other percentage it is displayed wrong.
How can I solve this problem?

Here are some examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>FirmaEmail</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices made by Photoshop (FirmaEmail.psd) -->
<table id="Tabella_01" width="620" height="260" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="15">
            <img src="images/FirmaEmail_01.jpg" width="620" height="82" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="13">
            <img src="images/FirmaEmail_02.jpg" width="410" height="18" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <a href="mailto:bagiacchimarco7@gmail.com">
                <img src="images/MailToBM.jpg" width="173" height="18" border="0" alt="Mail to bagiacchimarco7@gmail.com"></a></td>
        <td rowspan="5">
            <img src="images/FirmaEmail_04.jpg" width="37" height="177" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/FirmaEmail_05.jpg" width="276" height="26" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="6">
            <a href="http://bagiacchimarco.it/" target="_blank">
                <img src="images/SitoWeb.jpg" width="118" height="19" border="0" alt="Sito Web"></a></td>
        <td rowspan="4">
            <img src="images/FirmaEmail_07.jpg" width="16" height="159" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <a href="mailto:marcobagiacchi8@gmail.com">
                <img src="images/MailToMB.png" width="173" height="19" border="0" alt="Mail to marcobagiacchi8@gmail.com"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">
            <img src="images/FirmaEmail_09.jpg" width="118" height="7" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/FirmaEmail_10.jpg" width="173" height="140" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/FirmaEmail_11.jpg" width="222" height="133" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/MarcoBagiacchi" target="_blank">
                <img src="images/Facebook.jpg" width="21" height="28" border="0" alt="Facebook"></a></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/FirmaEmail_13.jpg" width="4" height="133" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/BagiacchiMarco" target="_blank">
                <img src="images/Twitter.jpg" width="22" height="28" border="0" alt="Twitter"></a></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/FirmaEmail_15.jpg" width="4" height="133" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/1/116064464482853449948" target="_blank">
                <img src="images/Google+.jpg" width="24" height="28" border="0" alt="Google+"></a></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/FirmaEmail_17.jpg" width="5" height="133" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/marco-bagiacchi" target="_blank">
                <img src="images/Linkedin.jpg" width="22" height="28" border="0" alt="Linkedin"></a></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/FirmaEmail_19.jpg" width="4" height="133" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/marcobagiacchi/" target="_blank">
                <img src="images/Instagram.jpg" width="25" height="28" border="0" alt="Instagram"></a></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/FirmaEmail_21.jpg" width="41" height="133" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/FirmaEmail_22.jpg" width="21" height="105" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/FirmaEmail_23.jpg" width="22" height="105" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="images/FirmaEmail_24.jpg" width="24" height="105" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/FirmaEmail_25.jpg" width="22" height="105" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/FirmaEmail_26.jpg" width="25" height="105" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spaziatore.gif" width="222" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spaziatore.gif" width="21" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spaziatore.gif" width="4" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spaziatore.gif" width="22" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spaziatore.gif" width="4" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spaziatore.gif" width="3" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spaziatore.gif" width="21" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spaziatore.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spaziatore.gif" width="22" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spaziatore.gif" width="4" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spaziatore.gif" width="25" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spaziatore.gif" width="41" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spaziatore.gif" width="16" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spaziatore.gif" width="173" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spaziatore.gif" width="37" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

I already tried to apply `display="block" float="left"` and to change pixel in %. 
It would be perfect if the image always remain, in any case, of actual size and that it is not possible to zoom. So not even loses resolution. 
Thank you.

Comment: using <table> for such a  layout is not a good idea

Comment: @charlietfl so, what is a better idea of this?

Comment: if it's a signature that will be used in email clients then a table is a good idea

Comment: @toast yes, this is an email signature.